# How to get marginnote to use the whole margin space?

Tags: margins, marginpar, geometry

I'm typing up a document where I'd like to add notes to myself on the side margin. I'm using marginnote and using the geometry package for specifying customized margins, I've allocated 5 cm for the left margin, but no matter how long the note is, it doesn't take up the whole 5 cm. Does anyone know why this is happening and is there a way to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{outlines,tensor,amssymb,amsmath,wasysym,ulem,multicol,textcomp,marginnote}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=5cm, right=0.5cm]{geometry}
\reversemarginpar
\pagestyle{empty}
%\marginnote{}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\Large \underline{Chapter 7 \textsc{Enzyme Kinetics \& Inhibition}}  
\end{flushleft}

\section*{Introduction to Enzyme Kinetics}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
  \1 Structural information doesn't give any information about enzyme's physiological role
    \marginnote{{\small So what do we need to figure that out?}}
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT:

So I downloaded the user guide to marginnote, and it says that I have to define the real width of the type area using `\marginnotetextwidth`. It says,

> Package marginnote needs to know the real width of the type area to
>   find the right margin. While some environments (e.g. thos of package
>   framed) change \textwidth, marginnote defines it’s own text width
>   macro. If you change type area after \begin{document} you should add
>
> \edef\marginnotetextwidth{\the\textwidth}
>
> after changing the type area. Maybe you should do this globally using
>   \xdef instead of \edef. Most users will never need to change
>   \marginnotetextwidth.

Does that mean I have to do this in the preamble or in the package itself? I'm a little confused as I tried to add `\marginnotetextwidth{5cm}` in the preamble but the compiler tells me, "Missing number, treated as zero."

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to tell **geometry** also the desired width of your marginal notes. Keep also into account that there is the parameter `\marginparsep` that should be non zero. Therefore something like

```
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=1.3cm, left=5cm, right=0.5cm, heightrounded,
  marginparwidth=4.6cm, marginparsep=3mm]{geometry}
```

should be what you want (4.6+0.3=4.9, so 1mm will be kept clear at the left edge).

The option `heightrounded` has nothing to do with the problem at hand, but it's better to specify it so that TeX will have less problems filling pages.

Answer (score 8):

After struggling, Googling and getting very angry with LaTeX, I figured out what I had to do: I use `\marginparwidth=%some_cm` in the preamble to specify my margin width while still using `\marginnote`. The code may seem awkward, but it works for me.

Comment: Or, alternatively, `\setlength{\marginparwidth}{5cm}` does the same thing, in a slightly cleaner (IMHO) way.

Comment: This solution often works better than manually defining the geometry for the whole document when using an existing style file.